# I am trying to hide data on the basis of certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to hide the data for a single column if the column contain value that is in exceptionList then it should escape and move to next but somehow i am not able to hide that and throws error

```
   if(x in exceptionList):
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

here is mine code

```
data = [['NISAMANEE ROWELL', '9198762345','98 Oxford Ave.Elk Grove Village, IL 60007'], ['ALICE BAISDEN', '8756342865', '94 Valley Rd.Miami Gardens, FL 33056'], ['MARC COGNETTI', '9198762345', '221 Summer CircleGreer, SC 29650'], ['JOHNS HOPKINS HEALTHCARE', '9654987642', '8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Number', 'Address']) 
df


def title_format(inp):
    return inp.str.title()
def new(x):
    #x = input('Enter your column name')
    #x = x.title()
    x = title_format(x)
    print(x)
    exc_list=['Mackesson Inc','Care','Healthcare','Henery Schien','Besse','LLC','CandP','INC','LTD','PHARMACY','PHARMACEUTICAL','HOSPITAL','COMPANY','ELECTRONICS','APP','VOLUNTEERS','SPECIALITIES','APPLIANCE','EXPRESS','MAGAZINE','SUPPLY','ENDOSCOPY','NETWandK','SCHOOL','AT&T','SOLUTIONS','SANITATION','SYSTEMS','COMPOUNDING','CLINIC','UTILITIES','DEPARTMENT','CREATIVE','PIN','employment','consultant','units','label','machine','anesthesia','services','medical','community','plaza','tech','bipolar','brand','commerce','testing','inspection','killer','plus','electric','division','diagnostic','materials','imaging','international','district','chamber','city','products','essentials','life','scissand','leasing','units','health','healthcare','surgical','enterprises','print','radiology','water','screens','telecom']
    exceptionList = [z.title() for z in exc_list]
    if(x in exceptionList):
        return x
    else:
        return x.str.replace(x, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8))

#new(df.Name.astype(str))
new(df['Name'].astype(str))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand you want, i change several lines in your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = [['NISAMANEE ROWELL', '9198762345','98 Oxford Ave.Elk Grove Village, IL 60007'], ['ALICE BAISDEN', '8756342865', '94 Valley Rd.Miami Gardens, FL 33056'], ['MARC COGNETTI', '9198762345', '221 Summer CircleGreer, SC 29650'], ['Healthcare', '9654987642', '8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Number', 'Address']) 


def title_format(inp):
    return inp.str.title()
def new(x):
    #x = input('Enter your column name')
    #x = x.title()
    x = title_format(x)
    print(x)
    exc_list=['Mackesson Inc','Care','Healthcare','Henery Schien','Besse','LLC','CandP','INC','LTD','PHARMACY','PHARMACEUTICAL','HOSPITAL','COMPANY','ELECTRONICS','APP','VOLUNTEERS','SPECIALITIES','APPLIANCE','EXPRESS','MAGAZINE','SUPPLY','ENDOSCOPY','NETWandK','SCHOOL','AT&T','SOLUTIONS','SANITATION','SYSTEMS','COMPOUNDING','CLINIC','UTILITIES','DEPARTMENT','CREATIVE','PIN','employment','consultant','units','label','machine','anesthesia','services','medical','community','plaza','tech','bipolar','brand','commerce','testing','inspection','killer','plus','electric','division','diagnostic','materials','imaging','international','district','chamber','city','products','essentials','life','scissand','leasing','units','health','healthcare','surgical','enterprises','print','radiology','water','screens','telecom']
    exceptionList = [z.title() for z in exc_list]
    match = [x1 in exceptionList for x1 in x]
    df.loc[match,'Name'] = ['X' * random.randrange(3, 8) for a in range(sum(match))]
#           return x
#    else:
#        return x.str.replace(x, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8))

#new(df.Name.astype(str))
new(df['Name'].astype(str))

df
Out[1]:

        Name            Number      Address
0   NISAMANEE ROWELL    9198762345  98 Oxford Ave.Elk Grove Village, IL 60007
1   ALICE BAISDEN       8756342865  94 Valley Rd.Miami Gardens, FL 33056
2   MARC COGNETTI       9198762345  221 Summer CircleGreer, SC 29650
3   XXXXXXX             9654987642  8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181
```

### More optimal way to do the same

```
exc_list = [x.title() for x in exc_list]
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(str.title)
df['match'] = [nn in exc_list for nn in df['Name']]
df.loc[df['match'] == True,'Name'] = ['X' * random.randrange(3, 8) for a in range(sum(df['match']))]
```

### To hide first 3 symbols

```
exc_list = [x.title() for x in exc_list]
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(str.title)
df['match'] = [nn in exc_list for nn in df['Name']]
df['NameIf'] = list(zip(df['Name'], [(lambda x: 'XXX' + s[3:] if len(x)>3 else 'XXX')(s) for s in df['Name']]))

df['Name'] = [n[0][n[1]] for n in list(zip(df['NameIf'],df['match'].astype(int)))]
df = df.drop(['NameIf', 'match'], axis = 1)
df
```

### To hide whole row

```
exc_list = [x.title() for x in exc_list]
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(str.title)
df['match'] = [nn in exc_list for nn in df['Name']]

hide_row = {c:'XXX' for c in df.columns}
df[df['match'] != True].merge(pd.DataFrame(hide_row, index = df[df['match'] == True].index), how = 'outer')
```

short explanation

```
# Step 1. this gives you DataFrame without matching

df[df['match'] != True]

Out[3]:
    Name                Number      Address                                    match
0   Nisamanee Rowell    9198762345  98 Oxford Ave.Elk Grove Village, IL 60007   False
1   Alice Baisden       8756342865  94 Valley Rd.Miami Gardens, FL 33056        False
2   Marc Cognetti       9198762345  221 Summer CircleGreer, SC 29650            False


# Step 2. this opposite gives you DataFrame with matching

df[df['match'] == True]

Out[4]:
    Name        Number      Address                                     match
3   Healthcare  9654987642  8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181  True

# Step 3. but you take only index from Step 2. And create new dataframe with indexes and 'XXX' columns

hide_row = {c:'XXX' for c in df.columns}
pd.DataFrame(hide_row, index = df[df['match'] == True].index)

Out[5]:
    Name    Number  Address match
3   XXX     XXX     XXX     XXX

# Step 4. And then you just merge two dataframes from step 1 and step 3 by indexes

df[df['match'] != True].merge(pd.DataFrame(hide_row, index = df[df['match'] == True].index), how = 'outer')
```

Comment: hey @Alexey how can i mask all the column on the basis of column masked  as when  name column is masked by XXXXXX for example  third row is masked  then remaining particular column and related to that row should also be masked

Comment: df[df['match'] != True].merge(pd.DataFrame(hide_row, index = df[df['match'] == True].index), how = 'outer') can you please explain this line i am bot able to get this line its working fine

Comment: Hi! I just have extended my answer

Comment: Hi! @Alexey  i have update my df last row name but the optimal way is not hiding 'JOHNS HOPKINS HEALTHCARE' as healthcare is in exception list so it should hide can you look into this

Comment: yes, right. 
All this solutions implies that for hiding row it require to full matching of value in column 'Name' with one of the value in exc_list. So for hiding operation must be True for this ('JOHNS HOPKINS HEALTHCARE' in exc_list). For this you shoud explicitly add this string to your exc_list, like exc_list = ['JOHNS HOPKINS HEALTHCARE', ..., ...]

Comment: Is there any other way without being explicitly adding in exc_list

Comment: It's not clear, what the desire logic of such filtration? How it should decides what row should being hidden? by what criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Just small change in your code will work, mind you that's not optimal but works just fine.

```
data = [['NISAMANEE ROWELL', '9198762345','98 Oxford Ave.Elk Grove Village, IL 60007'], ['ALICE BAISDEN', '8756342865', '94 Valley Rd.Miami Gardens, FL 33056'], ['MARC COGNETTI', '9198762345', '221 Summer CircleGreer, SC 29650'], ['Healthcare', '9654987642', '8522 Pendergast AvenueVilla Park, IL 60181']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Number', 'Address']) 
df


def title_format(inp):
    return inp.title()
def new(x):
    #x = input('Enter your column name')
    #x = x.title()
    x = title_format(x)
    print(x)
    exc_list=['Mackesson Inc','Care','Healthcare','Henery Schien','Besse','LLC','CandP','INC','LTD','PHARMACY','PHARMACEUTICAL','HOSPITAL','COMPANY','ELECTRONICS','APP','VOLUNTEERS','SPECIALITIES','APPLIANCE','EXPRESS','MAGAZINE','SUPPLY','ENDOSCOPY','NETWandK','SCHOOL','AT&T','SOLUTIONS','SANITATION','SYSTEMS','COMPOUNDING','CLINIC','UTILITIES','DEPARTMENT','CREATIVE','PIN','employment','consultant','units','label','machine','anesthesia','services','medical','community','plaza','tech','bipolar','brand','commerce','testing','inspection','killer','plus','electric','division','diagnostic','materials','imaging','international','district','chamber','city','products','essentials','life','scissand','leasing','units','health','healthcare','surgical','enterprises','print','radiology','water','screens','telecom']
    exceptionList = [z.title() for z in exc_list]
    if(x in exceptionList):
        return x
    else:
        return x.replace(x, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8))

#new(df.Name.astype(str))
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(new)
```